# android "walkie-talkie" using UDP multicast

Tags: android, audio, udp, multicast

i have to design a basic android app for voice communication. The UI has two buttons, button1 records and broadcasts in real time, while button2 lets the app receive audio from a device. So to communicate between two devices, One has to have button2 enabled while the other uses button1 for communication.

The network functionality has to be implemented using UDP multicast. The audio recording and playback has been pre-implemented, I have to implement the network functionality.

This is my code to send a recording.

```
    public void run() {
    try {
        byte[] pkt = new byte[MAXLEN];

        //setting up connection for UDP multicast
        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.1");
        DatagramPacket packet;
        MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket();

        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {

            int len = stream.read(pkt, 0, pkt.length);                          
            queue.put(pkt);
            Log.d("Audiocast", "recorded "+len+" bytes");

            //creating packet with buffered audio
            packet = new DatagramPacket(pkt, pkt.length,group, 3210);
            socket.send(packet);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        stream.stop();
        stream.release();
    }

}
```

This is my code on the receiving side

```
public void run() {
    try {

        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket pack = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length);
        MulticastSocket  sock = new MulticastSocket(3210);
        sock.setBroadcast(true);
        sock.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.1"));
        byte[] bSockBuffer = new byte[1024];
        //byte            []bRecvBufTmp;

        sock.setReceiveBufferSize(bSockBuffer.length);
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {

            sock.receive(pack);
            System.err.println("Received " + pack.getLength() +
                    " bytes from " + pack.getAddress());
                  pack.setLength(b.length);
            queue.put(pack.getData());
            byte[] pkt = queue.take();
            int len = stream.write(pack.getData(), 0, pack.getLength());
            Log.d("Audiocast", "played "+len+" bytes");
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        stream.stop();
        stream.release();
    }
}
```

The problem is once i connect an android device and load this app, i get the following error on logcat

03-17 18:29:35.505: E/(9532): Device driver API match
03-17 18:29:35.505: E/(9532): Device driver API version: 17
03-17 18:29:35.505: E/(9532): User space API version: 17 
03-17 18:29:35.505: E/(9532): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p1-01rel1 BUILD_DATE=Fri May 10 18:36:49 KST 2013

Once i remove all the queue related functions from the above code, there are no errors. Still it does not function as desired. The app loads, and logcat provides the following information(in a continuous loop) before pressing either of the 2 buttons.

Audiocast recorded 0 bytes /
Audiocast played 0 bytes

Pressing the record and broadcast button, changes the logcat output to

Audiocast recorded 1024 bytes
Audiocast played 0 bytes

again in a continuous loop.

Finally if i click play, that is the second button. the logcat output changes to

Audiocast recorded 0 bytes

in a continuous loop. Once i unclick the second button, i hear static noise. 
Can someone help me out with this, it would be greatly appreciated thank you.

This is the main activity class, in case it's needed

```
public class AudiocastActivity extends Activity {
final static int SAMPLE_HZ = 11025, BACKLOG = 8;    
//  final static InetSocketAddress multicast = new      InetSocketAddress("224.0.0.1", 3210);

Record rec; 
Play play;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_audiocast);

    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService( Context.WIFI_SERVICE );
    if(wifi != null){
        WifiManager.MulticastLock lock = 
                wifi.createMulticastLock("Audiocast");
        lock.setReferenceCounted(true);
        lock.acquire();
    } else {
        Log.e("Audiocast", "Unable to acquire multicast lock");
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    BlockingQueue<byte[]> buf = new ArrayBlockingQueue<byte[]>(BACKLOG);        
    rec = new Record(SAMPLE_HZ, buf);
    play = new Play(SAMPLE_HZ, buf);

    findViewById(R.id.Record).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                rec.pause(!((ToggleButton)v).isChecked());
        }
    });     
    findViewById(R.id.Play).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                play.pause(!((ToggleButton)v).isChecked());
        }
    }); 

    Log.i("Audiocast", "Starting recording/playback threads");
    rec.start();
    play.start();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    Log.i("Audiocast", "Stopping recording/playback threads");
    rec.interrupt();
    play.interrupt();
}
```

}

Comment: First of all, I'd say rename the '2nd button'. Change it to a status thing. If active, receive the broadcast. If not, don't. I'm quiet interested in this, so I'll give you a +1. If you don't have an example, I'd say check "Zello" (http://zello.com/) . It might inspire you with some of their functions. Goodluck!

Comment: the UI is not my priority atm, i need to get the basic functionality up and running first